# KSH88 variable inside script

Tags: bash, shell, solaris, ksh

I'm having trouble with KSH88

```
script="find . ! \( "$result" \) -mtime "$older" -xdev -type f -size +"$minsize"M -exec ls -lh {} \; | head -100 | awk '{print \$8}' | sort -rn"

files_to_delete=`$script`
```

When I Echo my files_to_delete variable I get :

```
find . ! \( -name '*.jar' -o -name '*.zip' -o -name '*.rar' -o -name '*.log' -o -name '*.xml' \) -mtime 10 -xdev -type f -size +100M -exec ls -lh {} \; | head -100 | awk '{print $8}' | sort -rn
```

which is what I want, when I execute it on the command line it works, but when I execute it in my KSH I get

```
find: bad option \(
find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list
```

Comment: Hint: Don't use variables! Use a function or an array to store the commands!

Comment: How to store it in an array or in a function ? I have an array of my exceptions (*.jar *.zip...) but I don't know how to use the -name and -o dynamically in the function ! P.S I read the duplicate link and didn't understand

Comment: Please try putting "eval " in front of the "$script", so it becomes files_to_delete=\`eval $script\`

I don't have a pure ksh88 environment to try this on, but it does make a difference in bash.

Comment: Why do you not replace `\(` with a `'('`?

Comment: The backslash escape is needed because find needs to have the ( and ) as parameters. If you remove the \, the shell tries to interpret it.

Comment: Simon3270: It's working \o/ thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put "eval " in front of the "$script", so it becomes

```
  files_to_delete=`eval $script`
```

This forces the shell to evaluate the command string.

If your shell supports it, it woudl be better to use `files_to_delete=$(eval $script)`. The ` version is easier to miss when scanning the script quickly, and much harder to nest (commands within commands).